# Deploye UWP app on WS2K12R2

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I have a question about UWP application. It's possible deploye this type of application for a Windows server 2012 R2 ?

Or it's only reserved for Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP runs on Windows 10 and Server 2016. Not 2012

Comment: Thank you for information. So to devellop for 2012 I can use CLR Project ?